# Re-import модулей при переносе кода

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, модули

Учусь работать в VS code - столкнулась с проблемой что для модулей после переноса кода в другую папку (чтобы он был более чистым) сломались все импорты. Как более удобно их восстанавливать в таких случаях? Сейчас я перепишу все пути - так как двойной клик или меню с при выделении проблему не решает, но в будущем хотелось бы знать как быстро работать с импортами модулей:( Может есть какие-то сочетания клавиш? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: обычно при переименовании файла либо переносе его в другую папку vscode сам предлагает поправить все импорты

Comment: в моем случае мне нужно было именно скопировать и перенести код - а не весь файл

Comment: тогда никак. при копировании невозможно узнать какой был источник чтобы определить какие импорты нужно менять

Comment: пока искала решение нашла вот эту документацию, но не поняла как ее применить чтобы у меня заработало :( https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_commonjs-auto-imports

Comment: это автоматически работает. Убираешь свои неверные импорты. наводишь на используемую переменную и по подсказке можно выбрать какой импорт для нее использовать